# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem when trying to inject a service on a controller. Decided to separate responsibilities to organize the code , but when I do this obetengo form error

This is the code

**main.js - require.js configure**

```
require.config({

baseUrl: 'js',

paths : {

  angular: 'libs/angular',
  ngRoute: 'libs/angular-route',
  ngResource: 'libs/angular-resource',
  index: 'app/index'

},

shim: {

    angular: {
      exports : 'angular'
    }       

}
```

In the ***main.js*** I call the main file to execute code

```
});

require(['index'], function (index){

});
```

**index.js**

```
var app;     

app = angular.module('AppUPC',[]);
```

Controller

```
app.controller('formulario', ['$scope', 'obtenerDatos', function ($scope, obtenerDatos){

    $scope.login = function(){

        var datos, usuario;

        datos = {

            Usuario: $scope.usuariotxt,
            Password: $scope.passwordtxt

        };

        obtenerDatos(datos).then(function (response){
            console.log(response);
        });     
     };         

}]);
```

Service

```
app.service('obtenerDatos',['$http', '$httpParamSerializer', function ($http, $httpParamSerializer){

       return function (datos){

            var url, method;

            url = 'http://190.109.185.138/Apipedro/api/login';
            method = 'POST';

            $http.post(url, $httpParamSerializer(datos), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

            }).then(function success(response) {

                 return response;

            }, function error(response) {

                 return response;

            });
        };   
}]);
```

Comment: I would recommend using angularAMD if you are trying to use angular and requirejs together

Comment: Your service doesn't return the promise.

Comment: How return promise @MinusFour,

Comment: I read about that @vbranden

Comment: `return $http.post(..)`

Comment: @MinusFour how pass url and datos login this way?

Comment: building off what minus four said, remove the .then in your service and return `$http.post(...);` you pass url and datos the same way in your sample code. by doing this you are returning the promise object and resolving it in the controller.